# fuzzy query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I followed this [**tutorial**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-query.html).
 
I tried with 3 data and it worked but when I add 200 data just as the tutorial "text and id" when I did the research it doesn't work

For exemple I have   `{ "index": { "_id": 237 }}  { "text": "EMCO"}`
when I do my research  as:

```
GET /weef/dicoMot/_search {"query": { "fuzzy": {
     "text": "EMCO" }}}
```

I got this:

```
{ "took": 36,"timed_out": false, "_shards": { "total": 5 "successful": 5, "failed": 0},
   "hits": { "total": 0, "max_score": null, "hits": [] }}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using standard analyzer with "lowercase" token filter.

so "EMCO" will be indexed as "emco".

There are two solutions to solve this problem:

1. Use **lowercase** keyword to search and get the search result:

   GET /weef/dicoMot/_search {"query": { "fuzzy": {
            "text": "emco" }}}
2. Update the index analyzer without **lowercase** filter

Comment: Yes ! 
how could I update the index without lowercase filter ? ( when I created it I didnt used or defined lowercase maybe is by default)

Thank youu so much